# How to Create a Torn Page Effect in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-effects

I saw an image as the 404 error in [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/somethings), and I wondered how to create such an effect in Photoshop.

[image: torn paper]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That image is a combination of torn paper and page curl.

[Spoongraphics.co.uk](http://www.blog.spoongraphics.co.uk) has excellent tutorials for both components:

- [Page curl](http://www.blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/create-a-realistic-page-curl-in-photoshop)
- [Torn paper edge](http://www.blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/create-a-realistic-torn-paper-effect-in-photoshop)

Comment: spoongraphics such a nice place...

Answer (score 5):

We actually use the same effect for the [404](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/404) and [error](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/error) page images on this very site.

[image: error]
[image: 404]

I tried the Photoshop way first, but I was never satisfied with the results. The problem I faced was not the end results didn't look good(in that faux way), but because they just didn't look "real." So what I ended up doing was taking a photo of the actual paper torn and cleaned up in Photoshop. It was so much more painless. Since papers are accessible to everyone, I recommend simply staging the paper the way you want it and photo/scan it in Photoshop.

The image you linked from CSS Tricks looks like a scanned photo to me, with artificial cast shadow.

Comment: Dead on, Jin. It's arduous creating it from scratch in Photoshop, and the real thing always looks more real. As versatile a substance as scratch is, it isn't suitable for everything. :-)

Answer (score 4):

i worked on the same thing ages ago, all you have to seriously work with selection tool when it comes to  edges i did all this with the help of "richard carpentar" given tutorial,edit and play with the details when working and you'll get your output, check this out surely it will help....

Tutorial :

- [Ripped paper effect Photoshop](http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/2008/12/08/ripped-paper-effect-tutorial/)

---

something very same....

Tutorial :

- [torn paper tutorial: please dont make it look like a flower :D](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/punch-through/)

[image: image from tutorial]

Hope this will help :)